# Prevent user from accessing subsequent url in django

Tags: python, django

I have a form where user enters answer for the question. If the answer is correct,user is redirected to next question.

Url pattern I follow for this is,
127.0.0.1:8000/question/1

127.0.0.1:8000/question/2 and so on.

am posting the form to the same view where the validation happens.But without form validation,user can access the subsequent url and previous url. Right now am not handling signup for a user . Any user can take up the Quiz. so in that case How do I prevent user from accessing urls directly?

I know this is a simple basic question.Am newbie in django learning by building something. Any help?.

Thanks in advance

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}{% endblock %}

{% block body_block %}

            <p><strong>Your question {{ quesno_id.id}} of {{ total_ques }}: </strong></p>
            "{{ question.que }}"
            <p><strong>Type your answer here :</strong></p>
            <form id='song_form' method = 'post' action="">{% csrf_token %}
                {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                    {{ hidden }}
                {% endfor %}

                {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                    {{ field.errors }}
                    {{ field.help_text }}
                    {{ field }}
                {% endfor %}
                <br></br>
                <input type ="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </form>

    {% endblock %}
```

---

```
def display_question(request,question_id):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    try:
        quesno_id = {'id':question_id}
        data = data.objects.get(id=question_id)
        total_ques = data.objects.all().count()
    except data.DoesNotExist:
        pass   

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = que_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():    
            user_answer = form.cleaned_data['answer']
            if data.name.strip() == user_answer.strip():
                if int(question_id) < int(total_ques):
                    return HttpResponseRedirect("/question/%s/" % (int(question_id)+1))
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('Game over')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Your answer is wrong")
        else:
            print form.errors
    else:
        form = que_form()
    return render_to_response('display_question.html',{'form':form,'data':data,'quesno_id':quesno_id,'total_ques':total_ques},context)
```

---

```
from django import forms  
class que_form(forms.Form):
     answer = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, a few things: 1st, I don't see you passing "question" to your template, but you call it ("question.que"). I also don't see you using "data" which you are passing. I'm assuming maybe you mean to be using data instead of question?

In any case, what you can do is something like this:

```
 if data.name.strip() == user_answer.strip():
     if int(question_id) < int(total_ques):
         return render_to_response('display_question.html', {'form':form,'data':data,'quesno_id':quesno_id,'total_ques':total_ques},context)
     else:
         return HttpResponse('Game over')
 else:
     return HttpResponse("Your answer is wrong")
```

and you could pass the question id back and forth from the form to the view function and increment it in the view function whenever the question is answered correctly.

UPDATE:

I'm not sure if this would work re: your comment, but you could try just using javascript in display.html. Something like:

```
  <script>
     $("#text-box").val("");
  </script>
```

My thinking would be that it would execute when you re-render to response...

Comment: Yes it's `data.que`.My mistake.I have implemented the way you told,it works but since am rendering the form to the same page(display_question.html) the previous value entered in the text box remains unclear. How to render new form without previously entered value?

Comment: See my comment... I'm not 100% sure I understand what you are asking, but see if what I suggested is what you need.

Comment: I tried it. The data is cleared in the text box right even before making POST request to backend django view code because am calling Js function to clear the value when the form submission is made.So i rendered the empty form again.It worked :) Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Django includes a tool called [form wizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) in `django.contrib.formtools` that seems to fit your need. It uses sessions/cookies in the form to validate the form pages are accessed in the correct order. You might want to look into how it works, or just use what is available without having to deal with things yourself.

If you want/need to implement this yourself, the most straightforward way is probably with sessions. Set a flag in the session when a question is answered:

```
request.sessions['question_{}_answered'.format(question_id)] = True
```

and check whether all previous questions are answered when rendering the next question. Something like...

```
for qid in range(1, question_id):
    if 'question_{}_answered'.format(qid) not in request.sessions:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/question/1/')
# Really renders the question page
return render_to_response(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd serve all questions from the same URL, i.e. drop the "/" part at the end - now users can't modify the URL to get to any other question. For GET requests, you can query the database for the first unanswered question (I'm assuming you store all the answers) and display that.

Comment: yes i tried doing that.I didn't know how to display only one question at a time in a form.So i gone with logic of iterating the `question_id` every time and displaying one single question for each url. May be some example could help?

Comment: In the code sample you provided, you call a function `que_form()`, does that give you a Form for the question? What does it look like?

Comment: Yes it gives me form for one single question/url.Please check my updated question. I have included `form.py`